# Timer NullPointerException

Tags: android, timer, nullpointerexception

I received a NullPointerException to one of the last lines of an activity regarding a Timer. What happens in the activity is 5 .ogg files is played one after the other. The error points to the the last TimerTask. I post the whole code, please do not get scared, there are many repetitions in the code. I don't know what did the user before the error, it doesn't emerge on my phone.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.b2creativedesigns.eyetest.AmslerGrid1$5.run(AmslerGrid1.java:343)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Partial code:

```
public class AmslerGrid1 extends Activity {

    Button btnFinish;
    Button btnMute;
    ImageView imgAG;
    TextView tvResult;
    MediaPlayer help1, help2, help3, help4, help5;
    int paused=0;
    long del=250;
    int intentcounter=0;
    int p=10;
    int length;
    private Timer timer;
    boolean out;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.amslergrid1);
        out = false;
        imgAG = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgAG);
        tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAGResult);
        btnFinish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAGResult);
        btnMute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAGmute);

        help1 = MediaPlayer.create(AmslerGrid1.this, R.raw.ag1);
        help2 = MediaPlayer.create(AmslerGrid1.this, R.raw.ag2);
        help3 = MediaPlayer.create(AmslerGrid1.this, R.raw.ag3);
        help4 = MediaPlayer.create(AmslerGrid1.this, R.raw.ag4);
        help5 = MediaPlayer.create(AmslerGrid1.this, R.raw.ag5);

        timer = new Timer("AmslerGridTimer");
        timer.schedule(TimerHelp1, 2000);

        help1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer cim) {
                if (paused == 0)
                {
                }
                help1.release();help1=null;
                timer = new Timer("AmslerGridTimer");
                timer.schedule(TimerHelp2, 1500);
            }
        });

        help2.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {...
        help3.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {...
        help4.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {...
        help5.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {...

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer cim) {
                if (paused == 0)
                {
                }
                help5.release();help5=null;
            }
        });

    }






    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (help1 != null)
        {
            help1.pause(); 
            length=help1.getCurrentPosition();
        }
        ...
        else if (help5 != null)
        {
            help5.pause(); 
            length=help5.getCurrentPosition();
        }

        p=0;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (help1 != null)
        {
            if (p==0){
                help1.seekTo(length); help1.start(); 
                help1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer cim) {
                        help1.release();help1=null;
                    }
                });
                paused=0;p=1;
            }
        }
           ...
        else if (help5 != null)
        {
            if (p==0){
                help5.seekTo(length); help5.start(); 
                help5.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer cim) {
                        help5.release();help5=null;
                    }
                });
                paused=0;p=1;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
      }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) 
        {
            out = true;
            if (help1 != null)
            {
                help1.stop(); 
            }
            else if (help2 != null)
            {
                help2.stop(); 
            }
            else if (help3 != null)
            {
                help3.stop(); 
            }
            else if (help4 != null)
            {
                help4.stop(); 
            }
            else if (help5 != null)
            {
                help5.stop(); 
            }
            Intent intentstart = new Intent(AmslerGrid1.this, MainActivity.class);
            intentstart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intentstart);

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private TimerTask TimerHelp1 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!out) help1.start();p=1;
        }
      };
    private TimerTask TimerHelp2 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!out) help2.start();p=1;
        }
      };
    private TimerTask TimerHelp3 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!out) help3.start();p=1;
        }
      };
    private TimerTask TimerHelp4 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!out) help4.start();p=1;
        }
      };
    private TimerTask TimerHelp5 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!out) help5.start();p=1; //error line. Maybe out is null?
        } 
      };
}
```

Comment: show strackstace and edit your source code to indicate which line causes the trouble. Doubt anyone will be trying to follow it all

Comment: sorry, i simplified the stacktrace concentration on the 5th element and added the stacktrace

Comment: if (!out) help5.start();p=1;  - I marked it at the end of the code. The variable out is false at the beginning (the user did not press BACK). When they pressed it, it becomes true. So if not true, help5 should be started. I don't know if the nullpointer error refers to out or help5

Comment: Well `out` is a `boolean` so it can't be null. So `help5` is null.

Comment: Any time you have to question "which of these variables is null", you should know how to set a breakpoint, debug, and inspect the variables to figure that out.

Comment: Apart from that the app run smoothly on 3 android phones I have as well as on the emulator so I cannot figure it out when the variable is null.

Comment: I have just noticed that I have two commands after the if, and they are not in brackets! I am going to check if this can be cause the error